# Web-Scraping with BS4 (Python) - Dataframe returning blanks

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to write a python code to export a weather dataset to a data frame. In the particular link,it does contain a map. In there we need to extract all the underlying data in it to a particular table. Such as ,

[image]

Below is the code I wrote

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://meteo.gov.lk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=102&Itemid=360&lang=en"
data  = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Location", "Status", "Temperature", "Rainfall",  "Reported_Time"])
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    col = row.find_all("td")
    Location = col[0].text
    Status = col[1].text
    Temperature = col[2].text
    Rainfall = col[3].text
    Reported_Time = col[4].text
    df = df.append({"Location":Location,"Status":Status,"Temperature":Temperature,"Rainfall":Rainfall,"Reported_Time":Reported_Time,}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

When running the above, the output gets null. i.e data frame is getting blank. pls refer the below

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Location, Status, Temperature, Rainfall,RH, Reported_Time]
Index: []
```

can you pls help me to solve this error? I am really new to python..

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML you get back, using View Source?  That HTML contains no `<tr>` tags at all.  The page is built dynamically, using Javascript.  You would need to use Selenium.  However, even with Selenium, the page I'm looking at doesn't have any tabular data.  It's a map.  They do have links to a data service, however.   You should look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored in a javascript array, which you can load as a dict with [json5](https://pypi.org/project/json5/):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json5
import re

url = "http://meteo.gov.lk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=102&Itemid=360&lang=en"
data  = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
scpt = soup.select('script')

# extract javascript array as python dict
data = scpt[22].text.split('mapdiv",', 1)[1].split(');', 1)[0].strip()
data = json5.loads(data)

# load dict to pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(data['dataProvider']['images'])

# extract data from description column
def extract_data(row):
    r = [i.strip() for i in re.findall('(?<=:).*?(?=<)', row['description'])]
    return float(r[0].split('&#8451;')[0]), r[1][:-2], int(r[2][:-1]), pd.to_datetime(r[3], format='%d/%m/%Y %H%M')

df[['Temperature', 'Rainfall', 'RH', 'Reported_Time']] = df.apply(extract_data, axis=1, result_type='expand')
df['Status'] = df['title'].str.split(': ').str[-1]

final_df = df[['label', 'Status', 'Temperature', 'Rainfall', 'RH', 'Reported_Time']]
```

Output:

|  | label | Status | Temperature | Rainfall | RH | Reported_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jaffna | cloudy | 31.2 | 0 | 65 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 1 | Mannar | Partly Cloudy | 29.6 | 0 | 75 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 2 | Vavuniya | Partly Cloudy | 33.2 | 0 | 70 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 3 | Trincomalee | Partly Cloudy | 32 | 0 | 60 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 4 | Anuradhapura | Partly Cloudy | 33 | 0 | 60 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 5 | Maha Iluppallama | Partly Cloudy | 31.4 | 0 | 55 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 6 | Polonnaruwa | Partly Cloudy | 33.8 | 0 | 45 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 7 | Puttalam | cloudy | 31.6 | 0 | 60 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 8 | Kurunegala | Partly Cloudy | 32.9 | 0 | 60 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 9 | Batticaloa | fair | 31.4 | 0 | 80 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 10 | Badulla | cloudy | 28.6 | 0 | 55 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 11 | Katugastota | cloudy | 27.4 | 0 | 70 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 12 | Katunayake | cloudy | 29.2 | 0 | 70 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 13 | Colombo | cloudy | 30.1 | 0 | 70 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 14 | Rathmalana | cloudy | 29.8 | 0 | 70 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 15 | Nuwara Eliya | cloudy | 19 | 0 | 75 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 16 | Bandarawela | Haze | 24.8 | 0 | 55 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 17 | Ratnapura | Haze | 28.9 | 0 | 70 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 18 | Monaragala | cloudy | 31 | 0 | 65 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 19 | Mattala | Partly Cloudy | 34.1 | 0 | 50 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 20 | Hambanthota | Partly Cloudy | 34.6 | 0 | 45 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 21 | Galle | Partly Cloudy | 28 | 0 | 80 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 22 | Pottuvil | Partly Cloudy | 30 | 0 | 75 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |
| 23 | Mullaitivu | Partly Cloudy | 31.3 | 0 | 65 | 2022-10-08 11:30:00 |

Comment: Very good catch with `json5`, +1. Only thing (if I would be nitpicking) - a more robust way of selecting the script with data would be something along the lines of `script_w_data = soup.select_one('''script:-soup-contains('pathToImages: "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/"')''')`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen thank you very much . works fine and smoothly. Thanks gain. Additionally I had t do some sort of a modification to the code because at some instances the particular columns getting issues. So had to apply the below code ----

    new_string0=string0.replace("XX","0.00")
    string1=r[1]
    new_string1=string1.replace("XX","0.00")
    string2=r[2]
    new_string2=string2.replace("XX","0.00")
    string3=r[3]
    new_string3=string3.replace("XX","0.00")

Comment: @Julien this is how people solve the issues. learn from him..  Dont try to find issues from posts and dont try to remove. People are coming here to learn something. If you dont know anything, please learn to stop messing with posts. Simply go away. I have just mentioned you because you only know to remove posts and always like to find issues in posts.